# Enlazador no enlaza

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gcc, enlazado

Estoy intentando compilar un paquete; en concreto, el *plugin* `gkrellm-leds` para `gkrellm`. Me he bajado los fuentes desde [packages.ubuntu.com/source/zesty/gkrellm-leds](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/zesty/gkrellm-leds).

Después de compilarlo e instalarlo, no funciona. El programa que debe usarlo, `gkrellm`, ni siquiera lo muestra como *plugin* disponible.

Como no es la primera vez que me pasan estas cosas, lo primero que hice fué

> `> ldd gkleds.so`
>
> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe15def000)
>       libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2fc6f37000)
>       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557eb4014000)

Yo **se** que este paquete usa las librerías GTK-2.0, además de otras. De hecho, el código fuente está lleno de llamadas a funciones de dichas librerías.

El `Makefile` del paquete es:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
VPATH = src:src/pixmaps

GTK_INCLUDE = `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags`
GTK_LIB = `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`

X11_LIB = -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -lXtst

LIBS = $(GTK_LIB) $(X11_LIB)
DEFINES =
LFLAGS = -shared
INCLUDES = $(GTK_INCLUDE)
CFLAGS = -ansi -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fPIC 
CC = gcc

SRCS = gkleds.c
HDRS = gkleds.h
OBJS = gkleds.o
IMAGES = leds.xpm

DESTDIR = 

INSTALL_PROG = install

.PHONY : clean
.PHONY : install
.PHONY : uninstall
.PHONY : test

#=======================================================================
#=======================================================================

gkleds.so : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $< 

gkleds.o : $(SRCS) $(HDRS) $(IMAGES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -c -o $@ $< 

test :
    $(MAKE) clean
    $(MAKE) DEFINES="-DGKLEDS_DEBUG"
    gkrellm --sync --demo -p gkleds.so
    $(MAKE) clean

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.so* *~ \#*
    rm -rf src/*~ src/\#*

install : gkleds.so
    @ if [ "$$UID" -ne 0 ]; \
        then PLUGIN_DIR=$$HOME/.gkrellm2/plugins; \
    elif [ -e /usr/bin/gkrellm ]; \
        then PLUGIN_DIR=/usr/lib/gkrellm2/plugins; \
    else \
        PLUGIN_DIR=/usr/local/lib/gkrellm2/plugins; \
    fi; \
    $(INSTALL_PROG) -d $(DESTDIR)/$$PLUGIN_DIR; \
    $(INSTALL_PROG) -s gkleds.so $(DESTDIR)/$$PLUGIN_DIR; \
    printf "\ngkleds installed in $$PLUGIN_DIR\n"
```

Todas las dependencias de compilación están correctamente instaladas, así como los `pkg-config` correspondientes:

> `> pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags`
>
> -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2
>
> `> pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`
>
> -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype

De todas formas, para asegurarme, *volqué* los resultados de `pkg-config` en un fichero aparte, `extra.mk`, y modifiqué el `Makefile` original para que incluyera el mio, añadiendo `include extra.mk` y eliminando las definiciones de `GTK_INCLUDE` y `GTK_LIB`.

Después de esa pequeña modificación, al hacer `make`, aparte de varios *warnings* irrelevantes, se muestra lo siguiente:

> gcc -DGKLEDS_DEBUG -ansi -pedantic -Wall -O2 -fPIC  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2  -c -o gkleds.o src/gkleds.c
>   ...
>   ... VARIOS WARNINGS ...
>   ...
>   gcc -shared -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lX11 -lXtst -o gkleds.so gkleds.o

Se observa como, en la última parte, llama a `gcc` con las opciones y librerías correctas.

Sin embargo, si vuelvo a hacer

> `> ldd gkleds.so`
>
> linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007ffe15def000)
>   libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2fc6f37000)
>   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557eb4014000)

**Sigue sin mostrar dependencias** de las GTK ni de ninguna otra, aparte de las añadidas *por defecto* por el `gcc`.

1. ¿ Porqué no se incluyen referencias a las librerías externas que utiliza el paquete ?
2. ¿ Como lo soluciono ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vale. Ya está solucionado.

Buscando en Google, terminé por encontrar una pregunta en StackOverflow:

[gcc build links but shared library does not appear with ldd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28088100)

En la respuesta *aceptada* se indica

> Most Linux distributions (I assume you are using Linux based on the output of ldd) seem to configure gcc as to pass --as-needed to ld by default (e.g., see here for Debian). This means the final library/executable will only depend on a library (i.e., have a DT_NEEDED tag for that library) if some symbol of that library is actually used by the library/executable.

Lo cual, en traducción *muy libre* por mi parte:

> Algunas distribuciones configuran `gcc` para que utilice por defecto la opción `--as--needed` al llamar a `ld`. Esto indica al enlazador que **no incluya** ninguna referencia a lirerías que **no sean llamadas directamente por el ejecutable**.

En mi caso, lo que estoy intentando compilar es **una librería**; **no es un ejecutable** y, con la opción `--as-needed`, el enlazador directamente *obvia* cualquier referencia a librerías externas. Se suponen que ya estarán referenciadas en el ejecutable que nos use.

La solución ha sido sencilla. Cambié el `Makefile`:

```
gkleds.so : $(OBJS)
  $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

por

```
gkleds.so : $(OBJS)
  $(CC) -Wl,--no-as-needed gkleds.so : $(OBJS)
```

Con esta modificación, se *invierte* la opción `--as-needed`; **forzamos** al enlazador a incluir cualquier referencia a librerías externas.

Después de hacer `make`, el resultado es el esperado:

> `> ldd gkleds.so`
>
> linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe22f5c000)
> libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff78143a000)
> libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0x00007ff781185000)
> libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007ff780f78000)
> ...

**Si se indican dependencias** de librerías. Tras instarlo nuevamente, **si** se muestra en la lista de *plugins* disponibles en `gkrellm`, y funciona correctamente.

### Actualización Ubuntu artful ( 31-10-17)

En esta versión, con `gcc -v`

> gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3)

`gcc` **no reconoce** la opción `--no-as-needed`. Es necesario indicarle **explicitamente** que la opción es para el *enlazador*. Par ello, y partiendo del `Makefile` **original**, la modificación ha realizar es la siguiente:

- Línea original:

  ```
    LFLAGS = -shared
  ```
- Línea **modificada**:

  ```
    LFLAGS = -shared -Xlinker --no-as-needed
  ```

Comment: Que trauma!! XD jejeje

Comment: @JacoboCórdova Lo *traumatico* es que el error está en la versión del paquete que viene con Ubuntu. Hace ya 1 mes que salió `Zesty`, y no hay nada en su *launchpad* ni ningún comentario por ninguna parte. ¡¡ Soy el único usuario de Ubuntu que usa `gkrellm` + `gkrellm-leds` !!